# STS Jar Remap Eclipse feature not working for a Gradle to Maven project dependency with "Web App Libraries"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I'm using the STS Gradle "Jar Remap" feature to a remap a jar from a Gradle project to a Maven project and I'm having some issues with "Web App Libraries" resources.

NOTE: The project I'm importing is called CrewAllocationTool but the pom specified the jar to be "stamps-cat". So I will use those names to distinguish the jar vs project.

I followed the instructions in [this post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/129267-how-to-use-remap-jars-to-maven-projects-feature). And that creates "Gradle Dependencies" which seems to do the remapping properly. i.e. when I open the project the dependencies update and the build path refers to "CrewAllocationTool" and when I close the project we have a link to the stamps-cat jar (I have "Jar Remapping on Project Open/Close" turned on).

However we are also using the Pivotal web server features which seems to be using the "Web App Libraries" resources not "Gradle Dependencies". And while when I open/close the CrewAllocationTool project the reference in the jar moves from the middle of the list of dependencies to the end of the list it does not actually turn into a project reference (ie it seems to rebuilt the dependencies but not turn the jar reference into a project reference).

Is there some setting I need to turn on or something so "Web App Libraries" will update properly?

Apologies for not having a SSCWE but it's a little tricky to set up with multiple projects etc so I'm hoping there is some quick obvious answer.

EDIT: I have added this to the STS bug tracking system here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4195

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Feel free to file a JIRA here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and it'd be nice if you could attach a sample project.